# enable field groups programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I have created a field groups programmatically using this code:

in *.module file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_api()
 */
 function field_test_module3_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {

      if ($module == 'field_group' && $api == 'field_group') {
        return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

## in *.field_group.inc

/**
 * Implements hook_field_group_info()
 */

```
function field_test_module3_field_group_info(){

 $field_groups = array();
 $field_group = new stdClass();
 $field_group->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default field_group disabled initially */
 $field_group->api_version = 1;
 $field_group->identifier = 'generale|node|field_esempio3|form';
 $field_group->group_name = 'generale';
 $field_group->entity_type = 'node';
 $field_group->bundle = 'field_esempio3';
 $field_group->mode = 'form';
 $field_group->parent_name = '';
 $field_group->data = array(
   'label' => 'Generale',
   'weight' => '2',
   'children' => array(
     0 => 'coverage',
   ),
   'format_type' => 'fieldset',
   'format_settings' => array(
     'formatter' => 'collapsed', //collapsible
     'instance_settings' => array(
       'description' => 'provo a creare un field group',
       'classes' => '', //generale field-group-fieldset
       'required_fields' => 1,
     ),
   ),
 );
 $field_groups['generale|node|field_esempio3|form'] = $field_group;

 return $field_groups; 
}
```

===================================================

Field groups is created but not dysplayed.
Bottom of the page there is a section "Disabled fieldgroups" where it appears

[image]

If it's enable there are no problem but I need that fieldgroups is activated automatically.
There is a way to enable this fieldgroups programatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code.

```
foreach($field_groups as $field_group){
    ctools_export_crud_enable('field_group',$field_group->identifier);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about where to put this code? I imagine that having it in `hook_field_group_info()` is not appropriate?